# Difference between "killing spree", "killing streak" and "killing spree streak"

Tags: word-choice

Often I see "killing spree" but is there any difference between "killing spree" and "killing streak" ? Or is it "killing spree streak"?

Comment: ‘Killing spree streak’ is not really a phrase that makes any sense at all, at least not without a _very_ contrived context. One might argue that some of the main characters in the _Scream_ films are subjected to a ‘streak’ of killing sprees throughout the movies, thus a ‘killing spree streak’; but it is not a natural phrasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relatively speaking, [killing streak](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22killing%20streak%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doesn't really exist as a "known collocation". There are only 550 instances in that Google Books link, compared to 44,800 instances of [**killing spree**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22killing%20streak%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22killing%20spree%22&tbm=bks).

But there are 102,000 instances of [**winning streak**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22killing%20streak%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22winning%20streak%22&tbm=bks), and only 1050 instances of [winning spree](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22killing%20streak%22%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22winning%20spree%22&tbm=bks).

I would say most of the "non-standard" usages above are from speakers/writers who simply don't know what the normal usage is. It's also worth bearing in mind the different definitions (in OED)...

> **spree** *- a lively or boisterous frolic; an occasion or spell of somewhat disorderly or noisy enjoyment.*
>   **streak** *- a temporary run (of luck). In phr. (on) a losing (or winning) streak.*

Thus, a *spree* is normally an *[extended, enjoyable] activity* you deliberately engage in (*shopping, drinking,* whatever). But a *streak* is a continuous series of *[good or bad] things happening [to you]*.

Comment: Great analogy! +1, I kind of understand the former and the latter more clearly now

Comment: @Orlando: I'm not sure "analogy" is the right word for anything I've written. Except insofar as this particular use of *streak* arises by way of metaphoric analogy to the core sense of *streak = [unbroken, continuous] **line***.

Comment: Yep, I was referring to that :)

Answer (score 1):

*Killing streak* and *kill streak* is a term, mostly popularized by gaming community, and video games in which it's used to describe an achievement of killing a large amount of enemies in a row (WOW, Modern Warfare 2,The Call of Duty etc.)

My assumption (and It's might be completely incorrect) that it's has to do with the fact that killing, in that type of games, equal to winning, so *killing streak* could be just another, more specific way to say *winning streak*. It also used more rarely, by some stand up comedians to describe *having a couple of successful shows in a row* as they called *killing* to have a successful appearance in front of a live audience, on a TV/radio show or on a podcast.